# How do I store a txt file as a two array of strings?

Tags: c, arrays, string, io

Right now I am stuck on how to take in strings from a text file and create two separate arrays based on those words. An example of the strings in the file is as follows:

BQN  Aguadilla, Puerto Rico

Format:

`<3 letter code><2 white spaces><a string up to 100 characters>`

There is a list of `100 strings` and I'm trying to create an array to store the 3 letter code only and another `array` to store the airport.

Code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1000

    int main()
    {
      FILE *airports;
      airports = fopen("airports.txt", "r");
      FILE *routes;
      routes = fopen("routes.txt", "r");
      FILE *flights;
      flights = fopen("flights.txt", "r");

      char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
      char air[100][3];
      char airp[100][100];


      if (airports == NULL)
        {
           printf("Could not open database files\n");

        }
      else
        {
          int i = 0;
          while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, airports) != NULL)
            {
              sscanf(line, "%s" , air[i]);
              strcpy(airp[i], line+5);
               i++;


            }
          printf("%s" "%s", air, airp);
```

There is more to this project so the code isn't complete.

I have included the printf just to see if the arrays worked. So far it just prints all of the 3 letter codes in a single line followed by only the first airport.

My description is a little confusing but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `printf("%s" "%s", air, airp);` That only prints the first element in each array. I'm guessing you want to put that inside the `while` loop and change to `printf("%s %s\n", air[i], airp[i]);`

Comment: And you should be wary of buffer overflows in your `sscanf` and `strcpy` calls.

Comment: Rather than indenting everything under your file open test, just test `if (airports == NULL) { printf (...); return 1; }` and complete your `if` block there. What you have done is fine, you can just easily end up more indentation than is necessary. In other words, you can get by without the `else`.

Comment: @kaylum Shouldn't the sscanf and strcpy put all the strings into an array of strings, therefore shouldn't the printf print out the entire array? If so I wouldn't need to put the printf into the while loop right? Also what do you mean about the buffer overflows?

Comment: @Peter Suggest you brush up on C pointers and arrays. Yes, you do have an array of strings. But you can't print an array of anything with a single format specifier. `air` by itself only gives the first element in the array. RE buffer overflow - each `air[i]` is only 3 bytes long. It takes 4 bytes to store a 3 character string because there is a NUL terminator at the end of every string. Furthermore, what happens if you get bad input where the letter code length exceeds what you expect? Good programming requires you to protect against any bad inputs.

Comment: @kaylum I've just started learning pointers so I'm not quite great at it yet. I have a question regarding the array. Currently with the codes I have the output is the following,   "BQNAUAAUSBDABOSBUFBURBTVCUNCLTORDDENFLLRSWHOUJAXLGALASLGBNASEWRSWFMSYJFKOAKONTMCOPHXPITPSEPWMPDXPOPRDURICROCSMFSXMSLCSANSFOSJCSJUSTISDQSRQSEASYRTPATUSIADHPNPBI Aguadilla, Puerto Rico" Why would it put all the 3 letter codes into one long line and only print the first airport? I am very confused...

Comment: @Peter I could explain it to you but not well in the comments. It's a conundrum of errors that leads to that result - you are not correctly storing the NUL terminator for each string and due to the way memory is laid out, all the strings end up being mashed together. But the bottom line is that you have Undefined Behaviour which means that no specific behaviour can be expected and any result is possible. It might be a good exercise to return to this to understand it at a later time when you have learnt more. But for now best just to fix the code and not worry about how UB is manifesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 100
int  getline(char ** lineptr, size_t * linelen, FILE * stream);


int main()
{
  FILE *airports;
  airports = fopen("airports.txt", "r");
  FILE *routes;
  routes = fopen("routes.txt", "r");
  FILE *flights;
  flights = fopen("flights.txt", "r");

  char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

  char air[5][100];
  char airp[100][100];
    int i = 0,lines=0;

  if (airports == NULL)
    {
       printf("Could not open database files\n");
        exit(1);
    }
  else
    {


        while (fgets( line,  MAX_LINE_LENGTH, airports)  )
        {
            for(int j=0 ; j<MAX_LINE_LENGTH;j++){
                if(line[j]=='\n'){
                    line[j]=0;
                    break;
                }
            }

            sscanf(line, "%3s" , air[lines]); //first 3 chars
            strcpy(airp[lines],&line[4]);   // the remaining chars starting from 4

            lines++;

            if(lines==100) // up to 100 line allowed
                break;

        }
      fclose(airports);
    }

    // printing the arrays
    for(i=0;i<lines;i++){
        printf("%d - '%s' - '%s'\n",i+1,air[i],airp[i]);
    }


}
```

Comment: Just a friendly tip: you're using `getline()` incorrectly. `pline` points to memory that cannot be freed using the `free()` function, violating that requirement stated by the [documentation for `getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) (you can also [view alternative documentation for the GNU implementation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).) If you want to test it, `#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 2`. In other words, `char *line = malloc(N);` is the correct way (or just `char *line = NULL;`). Otherwise, you could just `getline(&line, ...`

Comment: @Chrono Kitsune? correct, but there is enough space to hold a line, so it will not attempt to reallocate it, if i am not sure how line size should be i will pass a null pointer, and function will allocate memory for me, i will have just to free it. (but all that will just blow the code with unnecessary code right now)

Comment: @Chrono Kitsune, he defined  MAX_LINE_LENGTH to be 1000, that is too much for an airport name, 100 is acceptable and quit enough.

Comment: I understand your point. However, you're mostly defeating the purpose of using `getline()` and should just use `fgets()` to avoid the possible segfault, no matter how impossible the situation. You're not even storing the returned line length, so `fgets()` is the better (and safer) choice.

Comment: i think you are right, i will correct this right now

Comment: @milevyo So I tried exactly as you have it, but it didn't print out anything at all. I thought you wouldn't need the "&" in front of the arrays since arrays are pointers. When I tried it without the "&" it just said segmentation fault. I'm pretty confused... Also, shouldn't I need a "i++" somewhere to increment the array? Anyways, Thanks for your help! (It was also suggested by my TA for us to use strcpy to get the airport into the array)